# Qual é a diferença entre Promises e Observables?

Tags: javascript

Alguém consegue me explicar a diferença entre Promises e Observables? Gostaria de entender as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um. Qual é mais performático, qual aplica uma melhor prática para desenvolvimento e etc. Obrigado!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Talvez não saiba te explicar exatamente a diferença entre esses dois conceitos, mas se já for de uma alguma ajuda, dê uma olhada na resposta do seguinte link:

https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-observable-ou-promise-34392

Pelo meu entendimento a ***Promise*** processa um único evento quando uma operação assíncrona é concluída ou falha, já o ***Observable*** permite passar zero ou mais eventos onde o callback é chamado para cada evento.

Muitas vezes ***Observable*** é preferido porque fornece as características de Promise e muito mais. Com ***Observable*** não importa se você deseja manipular 0, 1 ou vários eventos. Você pode utilizar a mesma API em cada caso. Ele também tem a vantagem de "ser" uma ***Promise*** cancelável .

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Olá Z, pegue o conteúdo do Link e replique-o aqui, pois caso um dia esse link venha a quebrar a resposta continuará sendo válida.

Answer (score 10):

**Promises** são nativas do **ES6** e são ótimas opções principalmente comparada a callback, podemos viver bem com elas. Os métodos **then()**, que podem ajudar a resolver vários problemas, um bom exemplo seria encadeá-los tipo **.then(...).then(...)** . 
Métodos como **All()**, **Race()**... várias boas possibilidades utilizando apenas Promise. Contudo, ainda no **ES7** temos os Async/Await que só trabalha com Promise!

Para executar um **Observable**, é necessário utilizar seu método **Subscribe()**. Oi? Parece ser igual ao **then()**, mas não é! Enquanto em **Observable** pode-se realizar toda a programação com **map()**, **catch()** e tudo antes de ser executado, e então, quando disparar o **Subscribe()** ai sim... ai sim, será executado. **Promise**, após o retorno o que se faz com o **then()** é tratamento.

O que acabei de dizer, caracteriza um **Observable** como **Lazy** (preguisoso), já **Promise** como **eager** (ansiosas). Não confunda essa palavra com Jaegers de Pacific Rim! :o P

**Promise** vai executar e utiliza-se o **then()** para tratar. Já o **Observable** não, ele espera **Subscribe()** onde é quem realmente executa e trata (reativo).

Então é uma simples questão de preferência? Acredito que não! Mas, por ser reativo, **Observable** seria minha opção! Em suas posibilidades como da função **Retry()**, que tenta reconectar ou chamar a sua requisição novamente caso você tenha problemas de oscilação de conexão, por exemplo, é um ótimo recurso. **Promise** não possui essa característica reativa, porém **Promise** já é Nativa **ES6**, como dito no início dessa resposta. Não precisamos importar nada, **Observable** é uma alternativa já vinda do **RxJS** e precisa ser importado, e muito comum para dev **Angular 2+**.

Answer (score 3):

**Observable**
Por definição é uma coleção que funciona de forma unidirecional, ou seja, ele emite notificações sempre que ocorre uma mudança em um de seus itens e a partir disso podemos executar uma ação.

**Mas quais são as vantagens de usar Observable e não Promises?**
A grande vantagem está nos “poderes” que o Observable nos dá com seus operadores, por exemplo: Podemos “cancelar” requests para poupar processamento, ou até mesmo tentar fazer uma nova requisição caso algum problema como perda de conexão aconteça. O usuário não precisa ver aquela tela de erro.

[source](https://tableless.com.br/entendendo-rxjs-observable-com-angular/)

Answer (score 1):

Uma das diferenças é que utilizando **observable** você pode retornar multiplos valores enquanto em **promises** você retorna apenas um, exemplo: https://youtu.be/3rbikUwGf9Y

Outra diferença é que pra utilizar **observable** você precisa importar o RxJs que permite utilizar operadores como map, filter entre outros, como se você estivesse lidando com um array, porém não te permite utilizar async/await. Já em **promises** não é preciso importar algo pra utilizá-la e é possível utilizar async/await.