# O que são os observables?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

Gostaria q pudessem me explicar oq são os observables no Angular. Quais as suas diferenças pra uma promise?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Qual é a diferença entre Promises e Observables?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207362/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-promises-e-observables)

Answer (score 0):

Observables tem a função de avisar/notificar o angular sempre que ocorre uma alteração neles, por isso é muito comum utilizarmos Observables para as requisições http por exemplo. Ele é bem parecido com uma promise, ambos são assícronos, mas a diferença é que ele pode ser constante, ele pode notificar o angular varias vezes durante seu ciclo.

Recomendo que você faça  [este curso sobre angular](https://loiane.training/curso/angular). É muito bom! Para mim, é o melhor da internet.